# Can you 搬东西？ Or do you need to 搬家？

Tags: vocabulary

I'm interested in the use of 搬  in the case of moving in. Could I say "我帮了我的室友搬一些东西？“ or does it need to be ”帮了她把他的东西搬到他的宿舍里面“

Can you simply say 搬东西 ？

Comment: It's `搬`, not `办` or `般`.

Comment: **“哥们，你能帮我搬点东西吗”**，张三看着Stephen。Stephen想了一下，我先问问我女朋友同意不。 “宝贝，**我室友让我帮他搬点东西**，行吗，哦，我知道了”。张三挂掉电话，一边挽袖子一边说 "走吧，**搬什么东西？**” “没什么，**好搬，咱俩就能轻松搬走**”，室友高兴的说。 …… …… **“我不搬了，你爱找谁搬找谁搬，这玩意是人搬的吗！它搬我还是我搬它啊！”** Stephen看着眼前的黑猩猩说，“再说了，**你搬它干什么？**” 室友很无奈，说,"唉，我不是想让它生活环境好一点嘛，**搬来和我们一起住，给它搬家也经过它父母同意了**，” ………… “宝贝，**我今天帮我室友把东西搬到他宿舍里去了**” ………… …… **最终，猩猩还是再次搬家了。**

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm impressed or confused after reading that...

Comment: @user3306356 Focus those bold sentence,that's usage pattern of 搬. Don't mind the whole story.

Comment: Just notice we need HAND to move something, that's why 扌 in the left of 搬

Answer (score 1):

it seems you can also say： 我帮我（的）室友搬进来了。or 我帮她搬（一些）东西近来了。
have been looking for grammatical rules requiring 把-sentence as proposed below and only found the following: 外国人实用汉语语法，５０２页：the 把-sentence must be used when the verbal predicate takes a compound directional complement and an object of place. For example: 老师把新同学带进教室来了。 大夫把那个病人送回家去了。 我们把这几件东西搬上楼去吧。（however in present case object of place seems to be missing，进宿舍楼来 would have object of place）。There also is the following which may be relevant：实用现代汉语语法（２００１年北京）７４７页：１。当谓语动词有两个宾语，一个是表示事物的名词，另一个表示经过动作后事物所在的处所时，事物名词要与介词＂把＂结合放在谓语动词前，表示处所的词语放在谓语动词后，谓语动词与处所词之间还要用一个结果补语或趋向补语。例如：（１）他们把鸡蛋放在桌子上就走了。（２）他把照片递到我面前叫我看。（３）西门豹又叫人把三老扔进了河里。。。。（again， above there is no表示处所的词语）.另一方面＂在线词典＂一共有５０个为＂搬进来＂提供的例句，而其中有以下三个似乎证实用＂把＂字句是必要的，尽管没有表示处所的宾语：
椅子在花园里,请把它搬进来，请问，要把箱子搬进来吗？，不知道是否可以让孩子们帮我把箱子搬进来.It would seem that if ＊搬东西进来  is changed to 搬进东西来 then it might become acceptable according to Representation of Chinese Grammar with Diagrams 图示汉语语法（ISBN ９７８－７－５６１９－２７９５－３）１１８页 动词 既带复合趋向补语，也带宾语例如：脱下一件衣服来，拿出一个本子来 （当然＊把一件衣服脱下来 及 ＊把一个本子拿出来 很可能违背了 ＂把＂子后面的介引成分应当是说话双方已知的，确有所指的，这个规则。

Comment: 2nd have problems。It should：我帮她**把**东西搬**进来了**。or 我帮她搬了一些东西。 or  我帮她搬东西了。 You can't attach 进来了 without 把。